# How do you change $Q$ in thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics

I know that changing volume changes internal energy and work for an ideal gas. However how does one add $Q$ into it? what exactly is the mechanism for doing so?

I know definition of $Q$ is that it is the net heat transfer. But how does one transfer heat?

But how does one "transfer heat" isn't heat already energy in transfer? and is temperature gradients the only way to do this?

Comment: Are you familiar with the terms "conductive heat transfer" and "radiative heat transfer."

Comment: @DDD4C4U, you should add what $q$ means. And by the way, Chet Miller is talking about *conduction* and *radiation*-you should be familiar with *those* words, they are the modes of transfer of heat.

Comment: In freshman physics, they covered Fourier's law of heat conduction.

Comment: I haven't encountered this. However I know newtons law of cooling. 

According to wiki, it seems to be a continous analogue of newtons law which  I don't understand

Comment: [Heat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat) is not a [state function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_function), if that's what you're asking.

Comment: No I'm trying to understand different methods of heat transfer...

Comment: There's a bit of an ambiguity to the question.  Are you stuck on "...the net heat transfer. But how does one transfer heat?"   Or the mechanism by which heat works?  If the former, the issue may be semantics.   One does not "transfer heat", one transfers energy.  Heat is the quantity of energy transferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question you are saying ,If the definition of heat is "energy in transfer" then why do we speak of "transfer of heat"- how do we  "transfer  a transfer"
The second part is, what is the exact mechanism of that transfer . I will answer the second part first.

Heat is transferred in one of three ways. Conduction, convection and radiation.

Firstly you should understand heat and temperature are related but are not exactly the same. Heat is measured in Joules which is a unit of energy , where as temperature is measured in Kelvin , which strictly speaking is a measure of the vibration , rotation and translation of individual molecules.

For example a cup of boiling water has a higher temperature than an olympic swimming pool, but the pool  can be thought of as containing more heat. Although even that is not strictly correct -see part 2.

Conduction- 
Micro explanation- occurs when a hot substance comes into contact with a cold substance and the highly vibrating molecules at the surface  of the hot substance bump into less energetic molecules at the surface of the cold substance,and the collisions between the two cause the molecules in the cold substance to start moving more energetically. The ones at the  surface then bump into the  ones next to them and so on , so that  eventually all of the molecules of the formerly cold substances are now moving at increased level of energy.

Real world example- put  cold metal tea spoon into a cup of hot tea , gradually the spoon warms up.

Convection- Micro explanation- A large body of molecules with a higher vibrational level of energy expands because the molecules are pinging around more,  thereby  becoming less dense and so  moves up or across  due to buoyancy or pressure differences. As it does so it displaces a large mass of colder molecules. Note convection only happens in liquids and gases.

Real world example - place a heat source in a cold room , the air immediately around it will be heated by conduction but that air will rise up to the ceiling by convection . After some time the air near the  ceiling will be considerably warmer than the air close to the  floor. ( if you are ever in a house fire- keep your head near the ground!)

Radiation- Heat is transferred across space , even empty space by electromagnetic waves . The explanation of exactly what *they* are is a bit beyond me , but suffice to say it does not require any molecules in the space in between.

Real world example- on a cold but sunny day sit out in a chair in the sun, with a good book ( our your iphone!) with one side of your face,facing the sun. After 20 minutes or so you will feel that side of your face is quite a bit warmer than the other , even though the air temperature is the same all round you.

Part 2 - Because heat is defined as energy in transfer. It is not useful the speak of the "heat " of something in isolation. People say this way in common speech , but in physics terms, it only makes sense in terms of references to something else. Thus in the swimming pool example in part 1 , it's more correct to say something like the Pool has a bigger heat capacity, or a capacity to transfer more joules. 
If there is no transfer then instead of heat we talk of Internal energy (u)or enthalpy (u+pV).